# Dropdown that displays selected results with a "Add another" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Building a select drop down that displays the results of the selected off to the side in a span with "Results" prepended (similar to a label in a form input).

There is also an "Add another" button below the select that, when clicked, adds another "Results" div and allows the user to select from the same drop down and display the new results (SOLVED).

Additionally, when the custom option is selected a div with two inputs (height and width) will appear (SOLVED).

I'm having trouble cloning an element and appending it without it multiplying (SOLVED).

Also when the custom option is selected I am trying to get the div with the height and width to show, not sure why it isn't working (SOLVED).

Is there a way to show the results in the new Results span created from the Add Another button?  I keep running into an error where the choices update all of the results or only the first one.

So far I have this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kcw/DRyCU/)

HTML

```
<div id="exp-display-choice">
    <div class="exp-choices">
        <ul class="choices">
            <p class="results">Results:<span class="pet_select"></span>  <span class="transportation_select"></span></p>
        </ul>
        <ul class="ad-choices">
            <li>
                <select class="select" name="pet_select">
                    <option value="" selected>Choose Your Pet</option>
                    <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
                    <option value="Dog">Dog</option>    
                    <option value="Wookie">Wookie</option>  
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <select class="ad-size select full-width" name="transportation_select">
                    <option value="" selected>Choose Transportation</option>
                    <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                    <option value="Trains">Trains</option>
                    <option class="custom" value="Custom">Custom</option>                           
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end of exp-choices -->
</div><!-- end of exp-display-choices -->

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-btn button">Add another</a>        

<div style="display: none;">
    <p>Width:</p>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input custom-input" maxlength="10">
    <p>Height:</p>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="input custom-input" maxlength="10">
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    // Show Custom Ad Input fields
    $(".ad_size_select").change(function(){
    if ($(".ad_size_select").val() == "custom") 
    {
       //alert('test');
       // show custom-size fields
       $('.custom-size').show();

    } else {
       // hide the custom-size fields
       $('.custom-size').hide();
        }
    });

    // Add another results when button is clicked
    $(".add-btn").click(function() 
    {   
        var $newAddChoices = $('.results').last().clone().appendTo($($('.results')));
        $newAddChoices.find('.pet_select').text('');
        $newAddChoices.find('.transportation_select').text('');
        $('.exp-choices').on('change', "select", function(){
            displayAds($(this));
        });
    });

    $('.exp-choices').on('change', "select", function(){
        displayAds($(this));
    });
});

function displayAds($current_select) 
{
    var adChoice = $current_select.val();
    $current_select.closest('.exp-choices').find('.' + $current_select.attr("name")).text(adChoice)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
// Add another results when button is clicked
$(".add-btn").click(function() 
{   
    // THIS line you clone last `.results` and append `into` `.results`
    // It should append to its `parent` instead.
    var $newAddChoices = $('.results').last().clone().appendTo($($('.results')));
    $newAddChoices.find('.pet_select').text('');
    $newAddChoices.find('.transportation_select').text('');
    $('.exp-choices').on('change', "select", function(){
        displayAds($(this));
    });
});
```

Change to, take a look [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chokchai/DRyCU/1/) :)

```
$(".add-btn").click(function() 
{   
    // You should append it to `parent` of `.results`
    var $newAddChoices = $('.results:last').clone().appendTo($('.results').parent());
    $newAddChoices.find('.pet_select').text('');
    $newAddChoices.find('.transportation_select').text('');
    $('.exp-choices').on('change', "select", function(){
        displayAds($(this));
    });
});
```